# Dojo CompoButton - onClick event of MenuItem issue with its function

Tags: dojo

I have the following code in dojo creating a ComboButton with several MenuItems of the correlated Menu:

```
    testfunc = function (input) {
                                //Code that uses input
            }

            var menu = new Menu({
                id: "saveMenu"
            });
            //array has 10 json objects and each object has an "Id" field
            for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {

            var temp = array[i]["Id"];

            var menuItem1 = new MenuItem({
                label: "Option"+i,                
                onClick: function() { testfunc(temp); }
            });

            menu.addChild(menuItem1);
            }

            var comboButton = new ComboButton({
                optionsTitle: "Options",    
                label: "Combo",
                dropDown: menu,
 --->         onClick:function(){ console.log("Clicked ComboButton"); }
            }, "combo");

            comboButton.startup();
            menu.startup();
```

I need for each MenuItem its onClick function to pass a different variable in the testfunc. Specifically the value of the array[i]["Id"] which is an array that has 10 json objects. With the above code the parameter that is passed in ALL the testfunc functions of ALL the MenuItems is the last one.

Is it possible to pass for each MenuItem the correct array[i]["Id"] value

i.e.

MenuItem0 -> onClick: testfunc(array[0]["Id"])

MenuItem1 -> onClick: testfunc(array[1]["Id"])

MenuItem2 -> onClick: testfunc(array[2]["Id"])

.

.

.

etc

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem and I think I should share it.

The issue was solved by passing in the testfunc of the onClick event of the menuItem the parameters using the "this" token e.g.

```
var menuItem1 = new MenuItem({

                id: array[i]["Id"],

                label: "Option"+i,                

                onClick: function() { testfunc(this.id, this.label); }
            });
```